# ASP.NET MVC load balancing with nginx. Auth is lost after changing backend destination

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, nginx, iis

I have ASP.NET MVC app on IIS. 
When I deploy a new version of code my application don't response to requests from 10 seconds to few minutes. It's bad.
(maybe you know how it decide easier?)

I put nginx before IIS and set proxying all requests to IIS app. Then I made new app with the same code in IIS (1.dev and 2.dev). Nginx set request to both apps by round robin.

All are working, but auth is lost after one correct request. The second response receive with auth error. I check how form auth in mvc make auth cookies and found one that `.ASPXAUTH` is encrypted login with `machineKey` as key.

I generated `machineKey` and set it to both apps. When I set cookie `.ASPXAUTH` from one app (1.dev.domain.ru) to the second app (2.dev.domain.ru) with expire date - all work well.

But dev.domain.com - not work still.

**What I give wrong?**

**PS:** In each IIS app Bindings has:

- X.dev.domain.ru
- dev.domain.ru
  where X - 1 or 2.

nginx config - `proxy_pass` to `upstream` and contains these parameters:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://dev;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcame this problem.

I had `WebSecurity.Logout()` operation in code if `User.UserInRole(..)` processed with exception.

I commented this line and all are working well now.